# Add a windows 10 hotkey to send a command to a running application (Groove)

Tags: windows-10, global, hotkeys

My notebook does not have the "FN" hotkeys to fast forward to the next track in Windows Media Player/Grove etc.

Has anyone found a way to create a custom Windows 10 global hotkey to mimic what most laptops have built into their own custom hotkeys?

I think I found a program I can download to create them but I DON'T want to have to use some other app.  I want to know what the guts are for creating the command myself.

Comment: I will be adding custom hotkey actions to my app soon because of your question. Right now it is Virtual Desktop related. Check it out....https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Answer (score 0):

I realize you need the handler code for the hotkey as well. I will be back after baseball practice to show you how to send that message to Windows Media Player.

You're going to need to use the Window API for this. Specifically `RegisterHotKey`

```
[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);

[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
```

Here's a full Hotkey class to get you going. (There is some stuff you don't need in this class, but you don't need to worry about it)

In your case, you would use this class like this;

```
Hotkey keyMoveNext = new Hotkey();
//In the handler you just handle the next track skipping.
keyMoveNext.HotkeyActivated += MyHotkeyActivatedHandler;

    keyMoveNext.Register(Keys.W, true, false, false, true);
```

That's it.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;



public class Hotkey : IDisposable
{

    private bool _IsRegistered = false;

    private HotkeyWindow _Window;

    public int ClipboardNumber;


    public int _ID;
    public string ID;
    public Hotkey()
    {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _ID);
    }

    public string DesktopNumber()
    {
        return ID;
    }


    public event HotkeyActivatedEventHandler HotkeyActivated;
    public delegate void HotkeyActivatedEventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e);

    private bool _modifierALT = false;
    public bool modifierALT
    {
        get
        {
            return _modifierALT;
        }
    }

    private bool _modifierCTRL = false;
    public bool modifierCTRL
    {
        get
        {
            return _modifierCTRL;
        }
    }

    private bool _modifierSHIFT = false;
    public bool modifierSHIFT
    {
        get
        {
            return _modifierSHIFT;
        }
    }

    private bool _modifierWIN = false;
    public bool modifierWIN
    {
        get
        {
            return _modifierWIN;
        }
    }

    private string _key = "";
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return _key;
        }
    }

    public string HotKeyString()
    {
        string keys__1 = "";

        if (_modifierALT)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keys__1))
            {
                keys__1 = keys__1 + "ALT";
            }
            else
            {
                keys__1 = keys__1 + "+ALT";
            }
        }

        if (_modifierCTRL)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keys__1))
            {
                keys__1 = keys__1 + "CTRL";
            }
            else
            {
                keys__1 = keys__1 + "+CTRL";
            }
        }

        if (_modifierSHIFT)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keys__1))
            {
                keys__1 = keys__1 + "SHIFT";
            }
            else
            {
                keys__1 = keys__1 + "+SHIFT";
            }
        }

        if (_modifierWIN)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keys__1))
            {
                keys__1 = keys__1 + "WIN";
            }
            else
            {
                keys__1 = keys__1 + "+WIN";
            }
        }

        keys__1 = keys__1 + "+" + _key;

        return keys__1;

    }

    public bool Register(System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, bool alt, bool ctrl, bool shift, bool win)
    {
        if (this.IsRegistered)
        {
            this.Unregister();
        }

        _modifierALT = alt;
        _modifierCTRL = ctrl;
        _modifierSHIFT = shift;
        _modifierWIN = win;
        _key = key.ToString();


        //Dim keyAlt As Keys = (key And Keys.Alt)
        //Dim keyControl As Keys = (key And Keys.Control)
        //Dim keyShift As Keys = (key And Keys.Shift)

        uint Modifiers = 0;
        if (alt)
        {
            Modifiers += NativeMethods.MOD_ALT;
        }
        if (ctrl)
        {
            Modifiers += NativeMethods.MOD_CONTROL;
        }
        if (shift)
        {
            Modifiers += NativeMethods.MOD_SHIFT;
        }
        if (win)
        {
            Modifiers += NativeMethods.MOD_WIN;
        }
        //If (keyAlt = Keys.Alt) Then modValue += NativeMethods.MOD_ALT
        //If (keyControl = Keys.Control) Then modValue += NativeMethods.MOD_CONTROL
        //If (keyShift = Keys.Shift) Then modValue += NativeMethods.MOD_SHIFT
        uint keyValue = Convert.ToUInt32(key);
        //- CUInt(keyAlt) - CUInt(keyControl) - CUInt(keyShift)

        this._Window = new HotkeyWindow();
        this._Window.CreateHandle(new CreateParams());
        this._Window.HotkeyMessage += Window_HotkeyMessage;

        if (NativeMethods.RegisterHotKey(this._Window.Handle, _ID, Modifiers, keyValue) == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(HotKeyString() + Convert.ToString(" hotkey is already registered."));
            return false;
            //Environment.[Exit](0)
        }
        else
        {
            _IsRegistered = true;
            return true;

        }
        //Me._IsRegistered = Not (NativeMethods.RegisterHotKey(Me._Window.Handle, _ID, modValue, keyValue) = 0)
    }

    public void Unregister()
    {
        if ((this.IsRegistered))
        {
            this._IsRegistered = (NativeMethods.UnregisterHotKey(this._Window.Handle, _ID) == 0);
            if ((this._IsRegistered == false))
            {
                this._Window.DestroyHandle();
                this._Window = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsRegistered
    {
        get { return this._IsRegistered; }
    }


    private void Window_HotkeyMessage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HotkeyActivated != null)
        {
            HotkeyActivated(this, new System.EventArgs());
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("Hit");
    }

    #region " IDisposable Support "

    // To detect redundant calls

    private bool disposedValue;
    // IDisposable
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if ((this.IsRegistered == true))
                {
                    this.Unregister();
                }
            }
        }
        this.disposedValue = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void IDisposable_Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        IDisposable_Dispose();
    }
    #endregion


    private class HotkeyWindow : NativeWindow
    {

        internal event HotkeyMessageEventHandler HotkeyMessage;
        internal delegate void HotkeyMessageEventHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e);


        protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case NativeMethods.WM_HOTKEY:
                    if (HotkeyMessage != null)
                    {
                        HotkeyMessage(this, new System.EventArgs());
                    }
                    break;

            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

    }


    public class NativeMethods
    {

        private NativeMethods()
        {
        }

        internal const uint MOD_ALT = 0x1;
        internal const uint MOD_CONTROL = 0x2;
        internal const uint MOD_SHIFT = 0x4;

        internal const uint MOD_WIN = 0x8;

        internal const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;
        [DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "GlobalAddAtom", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = false)]
        public static extern int GlobalAddAtom([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
string lpString);


        [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);


        [DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    }

}
```